# The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type Listen

Tags: android

I'm trying to check if com.android.music is running and I'm getting the following error on this line `this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);`

error:

> The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type Listen

Code:

```
public boolean isMusicRunning() {        
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for (int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++) {
        if (procInfos.get(i).processName.equals("com.android.music")) {
            Toast.makeText(null, "music is running",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

If you could let me know what I'm doing wrong here that would be great!

Comment: What class is that? What does it extend?

Comment: the class doesn't extend anything.. I copied this code from another question.. Not sure what his class was extending either..

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`getSystemService` is a method of the class `Context`, so you'll need to run it on a context.

The original code you copied it from was probably meant to be run from an `Activity`-derived class. You need to pass a `Context` argument into your method if it's not inside an Activity.

Answer (score 22):

You should use that like this:

```
public boolean isMusicRunning(Context context) {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for (int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++) {
        if (procInfos.get(i).processName.equals("com.android.music")) {
            Toast.makeText(null, "music is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Both the answer are correct but no one point out the right solution to your problem.**

> You should use broadcast receiver to get current playing song.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String cmd = intent.getStringExtra("command");
        Log.v("tag ", action + " / " + cmd);
        String artist = intent.getStringExtra("artist");
        String album = intent.getStringExtra("album");
        String track = intent.getStringExtra("track");
        Log.v("tag", artist + ":" + album + ":" + track);
        Toast.makeText(CurrentMusicTrackInfoActivity.this, track, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

And add it onCreate

```
IntentFilter iF = new IntentFilter();

iF.addAction("com.android.music.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.htc.music.metachanged");

iF.addAction("fm.last.android.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.sec.android.app.music.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.nullsoft.winamp.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.amazon.mp3.metachanged");     
iF.addAction("com.miui.player.metachanged");        
iF.addAction("com.real.IMP.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.sonyericsson.music.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.rdio.android.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.samsung.sec.android.MusicPlayer.metachanged");
iF.addAction("com.andrew.apollo.metachanged");
registerReceiver(mReceiver, iF);
```

Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510292/track-info-of-currently-playing-music)

**Much better answer of 123 abc**

For simple check whether music is playing or not. Use

```
AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
if(manager.isMusicActive())//it checks whether music is played by Android OS
 {
     // Something is being played.
 }
```