# error when use getSystemService

Tags: android

i had this error `The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type WebAppInterface`  when I use " getSystemService". I worked in interface class not activity class .

```
 @JavascriptInterface
public void Viber(String value ) {
    if (value.equals("on")) {
        // Get instance of Vibrator from current Context
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator)getSystemService(mContext.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        // Vibrate for 300 milliseconds
        v.vibrate(300);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's cause the metod getSystemService belongs to the class Context, so you have to run it on a context but you're running it from an activity.

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void Viber(Context cn, String value) {
    if (value.equals("on")) {
        // Get instance of Vibrator from current Context
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) cn.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        // Vibrate for 300 milliseconds
        v.vibrate(300);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

for getting System Services from non Android application components you will need to pass Context to java class as:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void Viber(String value, Context context) {
    if (value.equals("on")) {
        // Get instance of Vibrator from current Context
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator)context.getSystemService(mContext.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        // Vibrate for 300 milliseconds
        v.vibrate(300);
    }
}
```

Or you can use WebAppInterface class Contstorctor as:

```
public class WebAppInterface{
Context context;

 public WebAppInterface(Context context){
   this.context=context;
  }
 ....


}
```

now use context for calling `getSystemService` as from `Viber` method:

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator)context.getSystemService(mContext.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference

[The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type Listen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963550/the-method-getsystemservicestring-is-undefined-for-the-type-listen)

`getSystemService` is a method of the class `Context`, so you'll need to run it on a context.

The original code you copied it from was probably meant to be run from an `Activity`-derived class. You need to pass a `Context` argument into your method if it's not inside an Activity.

Answer (score 0):

mContext.VIBRATOR_SERVICE  => Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE