# Missing getSystemService(String)

Tags: android, kotlin

I can't use `getSystemService(String)` from the Context library [I want to use it here, but it's missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DHE1.png).

[I want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZQ8W.png)

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/6963550/2111778

Answer (score 0):

Try to access with context object if you are accessing this method in non activity class.

```
  context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
```